# What are the differences between WebServiceBinding.EmitConformanceClaims and WebServiceBinding.ConformanceClaims?

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a xml web service like:

```
[WebService(Description = "The Calculator Web Service",

                            Name = "CalculatorWebService")]

[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.None, EmitConformanceClaims = false)]

public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService

{ 

    [WebMethod(Description = "Subtracts two integers.")]

    public int Subtract(int x, int y) { return x - y; }



    [WebMethod(Description = "Adds two float.", MessageName = "AddFloats")]

    public float Add(float x, float y) { return x + y; }



    [WebMethod(Description = "Adds two integers.", MessageName = "AddInts")]

    public int Add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }

}
```

I have read some articles regarding WebServiceBinding.EmitConformanceClaims and WebServiceBinding.ConformanceClaims. However, I could not find the differences between them. I got that confused because if ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.None then no matter EmitConformanceClaims = false or true, the above web service can be invoked successfully by clients. So, why do we need EmitConformanceClaims?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Setting `EmitConformanceClaims` simply means that when the WSDL of the service is requested, the claims set by `ConformsTo` are emitted.
- The conformance claims  (`ConformsTo`) is declaring what specification your binding adheres to.

So setting `ConformsTo` sets your specification level, and `EmitConformanceClaims` allows you to output (or not) the level in your service description.  Obviously if you set ConformsTo to None, there is nothing to emit, so `EmitConformanceClaims` has no effect.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very clear answer. I have one more concern. If I set ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1, then no matter EmitConformanceClaims = false or true, the above web service still take the effect of WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1. So, why is that? any mystery here? Thanks again.